# dshow source filter for rtsp streaming

Tags: http, directshow, rtsp

I have writed one directshow source filter for rtsp streaming. test by graphedit. when the network is good, the rtsp streaming can play normal. other case, the network is bad or the rtsp streaming file is special, the playing maybe hanld, no video, no audio. by the timeline go on.
I find the reason, for the streaming case, sometimes Fillbuffer(), no buffer for queue, so outputpin no sample send. DoBufferProcessingLoop() just do NULL again and again, until the rtsp receive data from network.  So I think this case, the source filter may send event for graphpath, like Pause event, but I donot know how to do.

Thank you for help.

some event like this, what is the value of "hr".
pFilter->NotifyEvent(EC_ERRORABORT, hr, 0);

Answer (score 0):

You can send events via `IMediaEventSink::Notify` but those are informational meaning that there is someone on top, the graph owner typically, [responding to the events](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd377532). It is basically not the task of the filter to pause the graph. The filter is supposed to notify on data starvation, such as in case of disconnection and attempt to recover. Or, fail completely.

Then the graph owner receives the event and decides what to do, to pause the graph or inform user.